# How can I delete from one table where rows exist in another table in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

What I'm trying to achieve is very straightforward but for some reason, I can't get it to work-- partly because I can't find any help specific to DB2.

I want to delete all records from a table if they exist in another table (these are both very large tables with 1m+ records). Here's what I've tried:

```
DELETE FROM dave.Last 
WHERE NULBERS IN
    (Select Substr(MSISDN,4) from a1313495.COMBINED_NUMBERS);
```

`dave.Last` is the table I'm trying to selectively delete from. I don't know if that works but it ran for a very long time, I had to cancel it.

I've also tried

```
DELETE t1.NUMBERS
FROM dave.Last t1
LEFT JOIN a1313495.COMBINED_NUMBERS t2 ON Substr(t2.MSISDN,4) = t1.NUMBERS
WHERE Substr(t2.MSISDN,4) = t1.NUMBERS
```

This does not work either as it returns `SQL Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104`. Surprisingly, the above query works when I change "DELETE" to "SELECT".

How can I achieve this? I need to use the most optimal method too because of the size of the tables.

Comment: What are your indices on DAVE.LAST and a1313495.COMBINED_NUMBERS? It seems not so much the SQL statement, but missing indexes.

Comment: @data_henrik sorry if this sounds stupid. I haven't worked with db2 before. I don't think indexes exist on either table. They were created just for this purpose (loading numbers into one and filtering with the other).

Comment: If you want things to be __optimal__  for tables with more than one millions rows, then define a primary key on both tables with columns that exist in both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I would suggest an expression-based index:

```
create index idx_combined_numbers_msisdn_4
     on a1313495.COMBINED_NUMBERS(substr(MSISDN, 4));
```

Then use `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM dave.Last l 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM a1313495.COMBINED_NUMBERS cn
              WHERE l.NUMBERS = SUBSTR(MSISDN,4)
            );
```